# find out value of check box after client clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the value of check box after client clicks it.

With this below it always returns the loaded value on the page but if the client changes it then it does not reflect the change? Thanks

```
var isChecked = $('#chkSelect').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Are you using an event handler to update the value on change?

Comment: But it **does** reflect the change, if the code you posted runs **after** the checkbox has been clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen for a `change` event:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZmY9/1/)*

```
$('#chkSelect').change(function(){
   // use this one if you need the object value
   var isChecked = $('#chkSelect:checked').val();       // returns value: on / undefined
   // or this one if you need a boolean value
   var bool_isChecked = $('#chkSelect').is(':checked'); // returns boolean: true / false
   
   alert(isChecked +' '+ bool_isChecked);               // test the vars result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#chkSelect').change(function(){
var isChecked = $('#chkSelect').is(':checked');
}
);
```

use of change handler for check boxes is more recommended then using `.click()` as state of checkbox can be changed without clicking it. Script above will update `isChecked` variable on every change.

Answer (score 1):

That's Because you're not attaching the code to a event. You could add the block of code when the user click in the checkbox like this

```
$('#chkSelect').click(function(){
     var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no click handler there.  You must updated onclick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $chkSelect = $('#chkSelect'),
        isChecked = $chkSelect.is(':checked');

    $chkSelect.click(function(){
        isChecked = $chkSelect.is(':checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client changes the value, you need to capture that via an event handler, .click() .change() etc.

So you'd need to add an event handler that accepts a function as its argument which will in turn take care of doing some action after the event is reported (in your case updating the variable isChecked)

Suppose your checkbox id is myChkbx

```
$("#myChkbx").change(function(){
  isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'); // will return true/false depending on the state
});
```

Also, this will not give you the "value" of the checkbox if you are storing some value in the check box via the value attribute of the input element e.g. `value="some value"` 
For that you'd need

```
$("#myChkbx").change(function(){
  isChecked = $(this).val(); // will return the value regardless if checked or not
});
```

You can try it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jggVd/)